# How can I use variables in system() functions? (Obj-C)

Tags: objective-c, xcode8, ios10

I've been looking for this answer everywhere and I can't seem to find it. Does anyone know how to use variables in system() functions in Objective-C?
Basically. I would like a system function in Objective-C to contain pre-set information with user input at the end.

I have tried `system(&"text"[variable]);`

I also tried `int command = "text"[variable];` then `system(command);` but I get `incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter if type 'const char *'`.

Comment: What are "system() functions"? This question is very vague. You should add more details. What have you tried. What code is not working? What would you like to work etc...

Comment: Basically. I would like a system function in Objective-C to contain pre-set information with user input at the end.

Comment: @0nedG Concat the data into a String and pass it?

Comment: What code have you tried and what errors are you seeing when you try it?

Comment: I have tried system(&"text"[variable]);

Comment: I also tried int command = "text"[variable]; then system(command); but I get incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter if type 'const char *'

Comment: Look at the error message. You are passing an `int` into something that does not take an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system() function takes a string which should be commands to be executed by the command line shell. So the string needs to be something you could type into the command line terminal. If you want to pass variables to the command you new to dynamically generate the command string with variable embedded in it, for example;

```
NSString.   * thePath = @"~";
system([NSString stringWithFormat:@"ls %@ | pbcopy", thePath].UTF8String);
```

to list the contents to the path in thePath, your home folder, and copy the result to the pasteboard.